# Is there a special name for a toolbar like thing at the bottom of Instagram?

Tags: mobile-application

[image: Name of the tool bar]
The attached Instagram snapshot has a collection of buttons like Home, Search, Add etc. at the very bottom. What is this component called? Is it called tab navigator? Any special name for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS calls this a [*Tab Bar*](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/), which appears at the bottom of an app screen and is used for navigation between an app's various functions.

It's not the same as a [*Toolbar*](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/toolbars/), which appears at the bottom of an app screen and contains actions relevant to the current view.